# Compression ratio (images) using Matlab

Tags: matlab, compression

Using `blockproc` and a Cosinus discrete transform (`DCT`) and a threshold, I just compress an image in Matlab.

I need to find the compression ratio, which is probably not hard to find.

It should be the number of bit in the compressed image / number of bits in the original image..

Using `BitDepth`, I am not able to have a valid compression ratio..

```
f1 = @(block_struct) dct2(block_struct.data);
f2 = @(block_struct) idct2(block_struct.data);

I=imread('autumn.tif','tiff');
Im=rgb2gray(I);

J = blockproc(Im, [8 8], f1);
seuil = find(abs(J) < 15);
J(seuil) = zeros(size(seuil));
K = blockproc(J, [8 8], f2) / 255;
subplot(2,2,2)
imshow(K);
```

How can I find the compression ratio using Matlab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to define *compression ratio*.

Let's agree that *compression ratio* is the amount of bits in the original image divided by the amount of bits in the compressed image. Since all values (DCT coefficients) are represented by the same fixed amount of bits, you can deduce the compression ratio from counting the number of coefficients instead of bits.

In the original image the number of coefficients is `numel(J)`, whereas it is `numel(seuil)` in the compressed image. The compression ratio for this image is therefore:

```
compression_ratio = numel(J) / numel(seuil)
```

For example, let's assume that your image dimensions are 640×480, and `seuil` contains 100000 indices of values below the threshold. Hence, your compression ratio is `640*480 / 100000 = 3.072`

Comment: My image dimension is 206 x 345 and numel(seuil) = 61915. So my compression ration is 206*345/61915 = 1.148?

Comment: @Pier-AlexandreBouchard Apparently. Not a good compression, eh?

Comment: with a bigger threshold, I think it would be a better compression ratio! Thank you!